How do I make Typescript understand a type guard on a property?
Why does Typescript, in the last line below, not understand that foo.required is non-null?
How do I make it work?
type Foo = {
  required: string;
  optional?: string;
};

function func(prop: Foo | string) {
  prop;
}

const foo = {
  required: Math.random() > 0.5 ? "req" : null,
  optional: "opt",
};

func(foo.required ? foo : "foo");

Playground link.

The problem is the null in required: Math.random() > 0.5 ? "req" : null - which leads to required being string | null though Foo declares required as a string

Yes, that much is clear. But with the ternary type guard I have in place (foo?.required ? ...), I expected TS to understand that foo.required is not null at the time of passing in foo.

You can reduce this example to this version where TS knows that foo isn't undefined and the same problem happens. That problem is a missing feature: ms/TS#42384. Checking the type of a property does not narrow the containing object. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes, spot on, thank you. At the moment, I have a somewhat clunky solution with a type predicate. Your input on what you deem the most appropriate solution, would be great.

You can use a user-defined type guard function as shown in this playground link. See the linked q/a for more information.
